# Using RVest to Create HTML Table And Then Using Manipulating and Cleaning into DF

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyr, rvest

I am looking to scrape the following web page:

https://kubears.com/sports/football/stats/2021/assumption/boxscore/11837

... specifically, the "**Play-by-Play**" tab in the top menu. Getting the information was pretty simple to do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://kubears.com/sports/football/stats/2021/assumption/boxscore/11837"

page <- rvest::read_html(url)

page %>%
  html_table() %>%
  pluck(27)
```

... and the result of that being:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  `Assumption at 15:00` `Assumption at 15:00`                                                    
  <chr>                 <chr>                                                                    
1 Down & Distance       Play                                                                     
2 Assumption at 15:00   Assumption at 15:00                                                      
3 1st and 10 at ASM19   Assumption drive start at 15:00.                                         
4 1st and 10 at ASM19   Turner,Easton rush for 2 yards loss to the ASM17 (Justice,Amani).        
5 2nd and 12 at ASM17   Exum-Strong,Khaleed rush for 9 yards gain to the ASM26 (Justice,Amani).  
6 3rd and 3 at ASM26    Turner,Easton pass incomplete to Collier,Bailey broken up by Meyers,Ryan.
7 4th and 3 at ASM26    Bertolazzo,Gabriel punt 46 yards to the KTZ28.
```

This is where I am getting lost though. I would like to take that information and manipulate it into various columns. As an example, this is a screenshot from Excel where I lay out what I would like the finished output to look like:

[image]

As you can see, I am taking the information from each individual play and translating the information to specific columns. Was it a rush play? Was it a pass play? How many yards were gained? Down, distance, yardline_100, etc.

And then doing that process for the entire play-by-play of the game.

Any suggestions and/or pointers on how to start the process would be appreciated. Scraping is certainly not my core strength when it comes to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a go by creating an `extract_plays` function, which basically parses through the Play column using with a series of `stringr::str_detect()`, `stringr::str_extract()` and `if_else()` functions.

The tricky thing is that there is some inconsistency in the tables at the start of each quarter which requires some special attention, otherwise the code should be quite self-explanatory.

I'm not an American Football follower, so please check some of the assumptions I've made.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://kubears.com/sports/football/stats/2021/assumption/boxscore/11837"

page <- rvest::read_html(url)

# set index for teams
teams <- tibble(team = c("Assumption", "Kutztown"),
                    posteam = c("ASM", "KTZ"),
                    defteam = c("KTZ","ASM"))

# grab the play pages from table
  plays <- page %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    .[27:47] %>% 
    # use colnames to extract teams later
    map(~rbind(colnames(.x),.x))
## note that  7th and 17th elements of plays are the 2nd and 4th quarter starts - different format
## 11th element is 2nd half start, incompatible table (not included in result)
  
# create plays extraction function
  extract_plays <- function(df){
    df <-  df %>% 
      set_names(c("Downs","Play")) %>% 
      mutate(team = str_extract(first(Downs), "^\\S+"),
             drive_start = str_extract(first(Downs),"\\S+$")) %>%
      filter(str_detect(Downs, "and")) %>%
      inner_join(teams)  %>% 
      extract(Downs,
              into = c("down","ydstogo","yardline_100"),
              regex = "(^\\d..) and (\\d+) at (.*)") %>%
      mutate(yardline_100 = ifelse(str_detect(yardline_100,defteam),
                                   parse_number(yardline_100),
                                   100 - parse_number(yardline_100))) %>%
      mutate(pass = +str_detect(Play, "pass"),
             rush = +str_detect(Play, "rush"),
             punt = +str_detect(Play, "punt"),
             special = ifelse(pass + rush == 0,1,0)) %>%
      mutate(play_type = case_when(str_detect(Play, "pass") ~ "pass",
                                   str_detect(Play, "rush") ~ "rush",
                                   str_detect(Play, "punt") ~ "punt",
                                   str_detect(Play, "field goal") ~ "fieldgoal",
                                   str_detect(Play, "kickoff") ~ "kickoff",
                                   TRUE ~ "other")) %>%
      mutate(passer = str_extract(Play, "(.*)(?=\\spass)"),
             rusher = str_extract(Play, "(.*)(?=\\srush)"),
             punter = str_extract(Play, "(.*)(?=\\spunt)"),
             tackle = NA,
             tackle = ifelse(play_type == "pass",
                             str_extract(Play, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))"), tackle),
             tackle = ifelse(play_type == "rush",
                             str_extract(Play, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))"), tackle),
             yrds = ifelse(play_type == "rush", str_extract(Play, "(\\d+\\syards\\s\\w{4})"),NA),
             yrds = ifelse(play_type == "pass", str_extract(Play, "for\\s\\d+\\syards"),yrds),
             yrdsgained = ifelse(str_detect(yrds,"loss"),-1*parse_number(yrds),parse_number(yrds)),
             complete_pass = case_when(str_detect(Play, "completed") ~ 1,
                                       str_detect(Play, "incomplete") ~ 0,
                                       TRUE ~ NA_real_),
             pass_breakup = str_extract(Play,"((?<=broken\\sup\\sby\\s).*$)")
      ) %>%
      select(drive_start,posteam,defteam,yardline_100,down,ydstogo,play_type,pass,rush,special,passer,rusher,yrdsgained,tackle,complete_pass,pass_breakup,punt,punter,Play) 
    return(df)
  }
  
## Grab for each quarter 
Q1 <- plays %>% 
    .[1:6] %>% 
    map_df(extract_plays) %>% 
      mutate(Quarter = "1st", .before = drive_start) 
  
Q2 <-   plays %>%
    .[8:10] %>% 
    map_df(extract_plays) %>% 
      mutate(Quarter = "2nd", .before = drive_start)
    
Q3 <-     plays %>%
      .[12:16] %>% 
      map_df(extract_plays) %>% 
        mutate(Quarter = "3rd", .before = drive_start) 
      
Q4 <-      plays %>% 
        .[18:21] %>% 
        map_df(extract_plays) %>% 
        mutate(Quarter = "4th", .before = drive_start)


 ## Grab the special cases for 2nd and 4th quarter starts     
Q2.1 <- plays %>%
  .[[7]] %>%  rbind(c("Kutztown at 15:00","Play"),.) %>% 
  extract_plays() %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = "2nd", .before = drive_start)

Q4.1 <- plays %>%
  .[[17]] %>%  rbind(c("Kutztown at 15:00","Play"),.) %>% 
  extract_plays()%>% 
  mutate(Quarter = "4th", .before = drive_start)

## Add to Q2 and Q4
Q2 <- bind_rows(Q2.1,Q2)
Q4 <- bind_rows(Q4.1,Q4)

#final table
result <- bind_rows(list(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4))
result
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 170 × 20
   Quarter drive_start posteam defteam yardline_100 down  ydstogo play_type  pass  rush
   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               81 1st   10      other         0     0
 2 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               81 1st   10      rush          0     1
 3 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               83 2nd   12      rush          0     1
 4 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               74 3rd   3       pass          1     0
 5 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               74 4th   3       punt          0     0
 6 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               72 1st   10      other         0     0
 7 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               72 1st   10      rush          0     1
 8 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               70 2nd   8       rush          0     1
 9 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               66 3rd   4       rush          0     1
10 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               61 1st   10      rush          0     1
# … with 160 more rows, and 10 more variables: special <dbl>, passer <chr>, rusher <chr>,
#   yrdsgained <dbl>, tackle <chr>, complete_pass <chr>, pass_breakup <chr>, punt <dbl>,
#   punter <chr>, Play <chr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to achieve your result using functions from the `tidyverse`. There are a lot of different ways to get the same results, this is just one way. The code is structured in three main parts: first, building a big dataframe by binding the rows of the multiple lists, second removing the useless rows that were in the original dataframe, and third create all the variables.

The `tab` dataframe is also slightly different from your `page` original input, see the code in the data and functions part. I basically changed the column names so that they are not the same and rename them `col1` and `col2`.

Only a few different functions are actually used. I created `extract_digit`, which extracts the nth occurrence of a number from a string. `str_extract` and `str_match` extract the specified pattern from a string, while `str_detects` only detects (and returns a logical, TRUE or FALSE). `word` gets the nth word from a string.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tab %>% 

  # Bind rows of the list to make a big data frame
  bind_rows() %>% 

  # Define the quarter
  mutate(quarter = str_extract(paste(col1, col2), "\\w+(?=\\s+quarter)")) %>% 
  fill(quarter) %>% 
  
  # Keep only rows that starts with a number
  filter(str_detect(col1, '^[0-9]')) %>% 
  # Create some variables
  mutate(drive_start = str_extract(col2, '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')) %>% 
  fill(drive_start) %>% 

  # Remove duplicated rows in the first column, keeping the ones with the longest string
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  slice_max(nchar(col2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 

  # ordering the rows
  arrange(quarter, desc(drive_start)) %>% 

  # Mutating part, creation of new variables
  mutate(posteam = ifelse(str_detect(col1, "ASM"), "ASM", "KTZ"), 
         defteam = ifelse(str_detect(col1, "ASM"), "KTZ", "ASM"),
         yardline_100 = 100 - extract_digit(col1, 3),
         down = extract_digit(col1, 1),
         ydstogo = extract_digit(col1, 2),
         ydsgained = -c(diff(ydstogo), 0),
         penalty = str_detect(col2, "PENALTY"),
         end = str_detect(col2, "End"),
         play_type = case_when(penalty ~ "penalty", 
                               end ~ "end",
                               T ~ word(col2, 2)),
         rush = +(play_type == "rush"),
         pass = +(play_type == "pass"),
         special = +(!play_type %in% c("rush", "pass")),
         passer = ifelse(pass == 1, word(col2, 1), NA),
         rusher = ifelse(rush == 1, word(col2, 1), NA), 
         tackle = str_match(col2, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")[,1], #Get word between parentheses
         complete_pass = case_when(str_detect(col2, "incomplete") & pass == 1 ~ 0,
                                   pass == 1 ~ 1,
                                   TRUE ~ NA_real_),
         pass_breakup = word(col2, 2, sep = "broken up by "),
         punt = +(play_type == "punt"),
         punter = ifelse(punt == 1, word(col2, 1), NA)) %>% 
  select(-c(col1, col2, penalty, end))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 128 x 19
   quarter drive_start posteam defteam yardline_100  down ydstogo ydsgained play_type  rush  pass special passer        rusher              tackle                     complete_pass pass_breakup  punt punter
   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     <int> <int>   <int> <chr>         <chr>               <chr>                              <dbl> <chr>        <int> <chr> 
 1 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               81     1      10        -2 rush          1     0       0 NA            Turner,Easton       Justice,Amani                         NA NA               0 NA    
 2 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               83     2      12         9 rush          1     0       0 NA            Exum-Strong,Khaleed Justice,Amani                         NA NA               0 NA    
 3 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               74     3       3         0 pass          0     1       0 Turner,Easton NA                  NA                                     0 Meyers,Ryan.     0 NA    
 4 1st     15:00       ASM     KTZ               74     4       3        -7 punt          0     0       1 NA            NA                  NA                                    NA NA               1 Berto~
 5 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               72     1      10         0 rush          1     0       0 NA            Nickel,Eric         Borguet,Keelan                        NA NA               0 NA    
 6 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               61     1      10        -7 rush          1     0       0 NA            Davis,Jordan        Allen,Edward                          NA NA               0 NA    
 7 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               68     2      17        10 pass          0     1       0 Nickel,Eric   NA                  Malm,Daniel                            1 NA               0 NA    
 8 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               58     2       7        -1 penalty       0     0       1 NA            NA                  Omokaro,Akugbe                        NA NA               0 NA    
 9 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               70     2       8         6 rush          1     0       0 NA            Davis,Jordan        Omokaro,Akugbe; Wright,Tr~            NA NA               0 NA    
10 1st     13:30       KTZ     ASM               53     3       2         0 pass          0     1       0 Nickel,Eric   NA                  NA                                     0 NA               0 NA    
# ... with 118 more rows
```

---

data and function

```r
extract_digit <- function(x, n) as.numeric(sapply(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+"), `[`, n))
# This function is a wrapper to get the nth occurrence of a number in a string.

tab <- page %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[26:47] %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% 
        tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>% 
        rename_with(~ str_c("col", 1:2)))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  col1                                                                                  
  <chr>                                                                                 
1 Play                                                                                  
2 Kutztown wins toss and defers; ASM will receive; KTZ will defend East end-zone.       
3 Start of 1st quarter, clock 15:00.                                                    
4 Krcic,Dean kickoff 65 yards to the ASM00 Easton,Brevin return 19 yards to the ASM19 (~

[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  col1                col2                                                              
  <chr>               <chr>                                                             
1 Down & Distance     Play                                                              
2 Assumption at 15:00 Assumption at 15:00                                               
3 1st and 10 at ASM19 Assumption drive start at 15:00.                                  
4 1st and 10 at ASM19 Turner,Easton rush for 2 yards loss to the ASM17 (Justice,Amani). 
5 2nd and 12 at ASM17 Exum-Strong,Khaleed rush for 9 yards gain to the ASM26 (Justice,A~
6 3rd and 3 at ASM26  Turner,Easton pass incomplete to Collier,Bailey broken up by Meye~
7 4th and 3 at ASM26  Bertolazzo,Gabriel punt 46 yards to the KTZ28.
# ...
```